Как заставиться работать операцию "Выполнить Javascript" в программе ADSpower
Работаю над автоматизацией прогрева аккаунтов в твиттере(скрол экрана) через функцию RPA в программе ADSpower.В данной программе существует функция RPA в которой с помощью операций можно выстроить свою схему автоматизации приложения. Одна из операций называется "Выполнить JavaScript" ,используя которую можно выполнить нужное действие с помощью JavaScript кода.В данной операции есть три основные графы:JavaScript/Вводить переменные/Return ValueСохранить в.
[
Примечание.В поле "Вводить переменные" нельзя вводить свои значения,можно ставить только те,которые предлагает программа.(Фото приложу снизу)

Не могу разобраться как работает эта опция и что нужно вводить в три основные графы для того чтобы скрипт заработал.Обращался по вопросу в техподдержку на что они мне ответили что не имеют специалистов в области RPA и скинули ссылки на  сайт с гайдами по использованию RPA,в котором я тоже ничего полезного не нашел(ссылки прикреплю)
Руководство пользователя RPA 
Основные инструкции RPA
Единственное из полезного,что я нашел на сайте является табличка с информацией про то что нужно вводить в каждое из полей операции

Пробовал ввести в первое поле  JavaScript ниженаписанный код,в поле Вводить переменные выбрал "ScrollResult",в поле Return ValueСохранить в "scrollResult" в итоге скрипт просто не срабатывает
Ниже приведу код который я хочу вставить в данную операцию
function smoothScrollForDuration(duration) {
const scrollStep = 50; // Шаг прокрутки в пикселях
const baseInterval = 100; // Базовый интервал между прокрутками в миллисекундах
const totalScrolls = duration / baseInterval; // Общее количество прокруток за заданное время
let scrollCount = 0;
let timeScrolled = 0;

function getRandomDelay() {
    // Возвращает случайное время задержки от 2 до 4 секунд (в миллисекундах)
    return Math.random() * (4000 - 2000) + 2000;
}

function getRandomScrollTime() {
    // Возвращает случайное время прокрутки от 5 до 15 секунд (в миллисекундах)
    return Math.random() * (15000 - 5000) + 5000;
}

let nextStopTime = getRandomScrollTime(); // Первоначальное случайное время до остановки

function scroll() {
    if (scrollCount < totalScrolls) {
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollStep); // Прокрутка на шаг
        scrollCount++;
        timeScrolled += baseInterval;

        if (timeScrolled >= nextStopTime) { // Проверка, прошло ли случайное время до остановки
            clearInterval(scrollInterval); // Останавливаем текущий интервал
            setTimeout(() => {
                nextStopTime = getRandomScrollTime(); // Устанавливаем новое случайное время до следующей остановки
                timeScrolled = 0; // Сбрасываем счетчик времени прокрутки
                scrollInterval = setInterval(scroll, baseInterval); // Перезапускаем прокрутку после задержки
            }, getRandomDelay());
        }
    } else {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval); // Остановка прокрутки после достижения времени
    }
}

let scrollInterval = setInterval(scroll, baseInterval); // Установка интервала для прокрутки

}
// Запуск функции плавной прокрутки ленты на 8 минут (480000 миллисекунд)
smoothScrollForDuration(480000);
